# Vagrantfile: permission attributes on specific (if possible multiple) folders

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

This is what I have right now in my `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "dev/", "/vagrant/dev",
owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
```

What I want, is something like this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "dev/", "/vagrant/dev"

config.vm.chown "/vagrant/dev/**/wp-content",
owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
```

So I want to set the default permission attributes on specific folders inside the `dev` folder, like `wp-content`.

Comment: you can run a shell script command to do this

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I have tried chown via ssh, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a shell provisioner to your Vagrantfile...

```
config.vm.provision "shell",
  inline: "find /vagrant/dev -type d -name wp-content | sudo xargs chown www-data:www-data"
```

The synced folders will already be mounted when this provisioner runs, so it should chown the directories as expected.